# How to export a shapefile through the Wikimapia API?

Tags: shapefile, api, wikimapia

I am trying to download a kml file from Wikimapia containing information on quaters (districts), the very same information that is nicely available on Wikimapia. What I want to get at the end of the day is a shapefile containing as many polygons as there are districts in Milan to use in my GIS.

This is my URL for the query I pasted in my web browser.

```
http://api.wikimapia.org/?function=box&key=[mykey]&lon_min=8.936&lat_min=45.282&lon_max=9.421&lat_max=45.652&format=kml&category=quarters
```

From this I get a tiny kml.part file, that I then rename .kml. The file doesn't open in Google Earth or QGIS. If I open it with a text editor I can just few lines of xml, but no information concerning my geometries...

Am I doing something logically wrong?

Comment: I cant see any solution for exporting the shapefiles from Wikimapia. Can you be more specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use category=5339 (instead of category=quarters) in your URL.

```
http://api.wikimapia.org/?function=box&key=insert_key_here&lon_min=9.05&lat_min=45.38&lon_max=9.28&lat_max=45.54&format=kml&count=1000&category=5339
```

This [list](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwCoBbn-eMHmNGE2NDRkYjItMDAzMS00N2Q3LWFjNjYtYTAwN2FkODE3NWI0/edit?pli=1) of Wikimapia categories definitely helped out (thanks @LarsVegas).

Searching for the word 'quarters' in the list of categories did the trick.

I also added count=1000 just in case there are more than 50 quarters (the number of features returned defaults to 50 if you don't specify a count, see http://wikimapia.org/api/)

Answer (score 2):

By a look at the [wiki for API box](http://wikimapia.org/wiki/API_box) I think you need to change your code either to (replace `key` and the coordinates with your own of course):

```
http://api.wikimapia.org/?function=box&bbox=37.617188,55.677586,37.70507,55.7271128format=kml&key=KEY
```

or

```
http://api.wikimapia.org/?function=box&lon_min=37.617188&lat_min=55.677586&lon_max=37.70507&lat_max=55.7271128&format=kml&key=KEY
```

There is also an example of how your result file is suppose to look like. Something I'm not sure about is the category. Maybe you should check the [complete list](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwCoBbn-eMHmNGE2NDRkYjItMDAzMS00N2Q3LWFjNjYtYTAwN2FkODE3NWI0/edit?pli=1) so you can use an ID or try it without using this parameter to see if you get a valid result then.

Comment: Doesn't look any different than the URL in the question.

Comment: Posted the 2nd example twice. Edited my answer.

Comment: Francesco's URL is fine.  I tried to get it to show those quarters in Google Earth and it just doesn't want to do it.

Comment: What happens if you leave the category parameter be?

Comment: One interesting thing though is 2827 (quarters) isn't on that category list.  The API is in beta . . . I suppose that may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Global Administrative Boundaries](http://www.gadm.org/) of the world would be of use also. This is a shapefile of most political districts of the world.